# Better way Create Image Thumbnails Using PHP

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails

I need to three size of images uploads for display in my page: `1-large 2-medium 3-small` now i have Two choices and two way .

1 - when upload images, PHP GD Library generate three size of images and put in any folder : example : in `/images/` folder

```
test-larg.jpg 

test-medium.jpg 

test-small.jpg
```

And Display :

```
<img src="/images/test-small.jpg" alt="">
```

2 - i upload original images and put in any folder. then, for each size (large/medium/small) generate image using  GD library from images. example : [TimThumbs](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/) / [phpthumbs()](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net) etc...

method :

```
<img src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=/images/whatever.jpg&h=150&w=150&zc=1" alt="">
```

better way ? better choices ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to combine the two approaches:

- On image upload, do nothing (apart from maybe adding the image metadata to a databse if so desired)
- On a call to "thumbnail.php?src=/images/whatever.jpg&h=150&w=150&foo=bar" see, if you already have this image in this size - if yes, give it back, if no create it and store it as a file

This means,

- you only create images you really need, thus saving CPU and storage
- you have to clean up your cache, if you delete/replace an image

Comment: Thanks, your mean : if i upload images without import data in DB, my method 1, if i upload images and import any data in DB (title/description etc..) and updated this my choices method 2. which way thus saving CPU and Storage ? thanks